# GGTS: Grails errors during making project org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException

Tags: exception, grails, startup

I know that this question have been discussed many time, but i didn't find solution for resolve my situation.. here is: I had started a new project in GGTS 3.4. I used Java JRE 7. In Preferences of GGTS, Java (Installed JREs) has this location: 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51` and `tools.jar` included in jre's.
Also I have those settings in my Environment Variables:

```
C:\grails-2.2.4
C:\Program Files\Groovy\Groovy-2.2.1
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
PATH: %GROOVY_HOME%\bin;C:\grails-2.2.4\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

`startGrails.bat` have been started using console

So, when I tried to make new project by `File - New -Grails Project`, I had an error:

> Loading Grails 2.2.4 | Configuring classpath | Error
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed:
>   _*CreateApp*: 1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 1. 1 error | Error     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:359) |
>   Error     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:137)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236) |
>   Error     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:903)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:566)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:542)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:519)
>   | Error   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:498)bla
>   bla bla

please, provide a solution for resolve this problem.

Cheers!